# Page anchor going under fixed navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a fixed navbar and header at the top of my page. But I also had some pages set up to link to specific sections.

Now, when I click those links it loads the page with the top under the navbar area(this is the issue I'm having). I'd like it to show up flush with the navbar. (this would be my "desired behaviour, FYI).

Here is my site:

Link: http://project7.byethost22.com/classes.php#sectYouth

Comment: You'll probably need to use javascript to fix this.

Comment: Like a script that auto scrolls the page to the top on load?

Comment: When you set an element to be "fixed", it essentially floats above the page -- so those links are working as expected -- it loads them so they hit the top of the browser window; though they are being covered by the header.  you will probably need to figure out a way to offset them, either through a margin, padding, or like @BrianGlaz said, javascript.

Comment: Would it be better to use a margin or padding or the javascript? Which would provide a more seamless looking solution?

Comment: I was just about to answer what @Rafael said -- he just beat me to it

Comment: Hi there. As per my comment on your other question, would you consider adding the essence of the site you refer to to the question? At present, if you repair the remote site (as you may have done already) then any readers wanting to follow the question and its answer will not be able to do so. The same will happen if the link breaks too (we have to deal with borked links quite often, and sadly posts that otherwise would have been good to keep have to be deleted).

Comment: As I said in my post, I'm happy to add code to the question. However, with how complex my code is I'm not sure what to add. I'll try to take a look at it and see but atm I'm unsure.

Comment: OK, thanks. One other approach - useful for debugging anyway - is to recreate the problem in a small demo project. If you can do that, what you create is going to be the smallest possible project that replicates the issue - and you can add that.

Comment: (Btw, please use `@halfer` or whatever other name here - I didn't get a notification for your message).

Comment: (Also, in relation to this question, if you can improve it - and please do - it can be taken off hold too. The on hold status is not permanent on any question).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `:target` pseudo-class and set `padding-top` to the height of the floating header and `margin-top` to negative height of the header.
Small code snippet:

```
#wrapper > section:target {
    padding-top: 100px;
    margin-top: -100px;
}
```

Comment: Oh thats a very interesting idea. Gonna play with that for a bit and report my findings

Comment: I am using the fact, that browsers scroll the page to the border area of the element, ignoring margin area. I am not sure if it works without flaws in every browser and every layout, though, please make sure to test in all the browsers you need to support. If you need to support browsers without `:target` support, you can apply the rules to every section in the wrapper. Visually it should not make any difference, since the negative margin visually "unsets" the padding.

Comment: This is a perfect solution! I really appreciate your help man! Nice to know some people on here still care about actually helping the poster! Same goes to Jared and Brian! :)